# Trying to replace Input with P

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I am trying to replace the input with the P element which contains what was written on the Input. I have tried not making the if, but it still won't work. the whole replaceWith is just not working. The end result would be the P element with the attributes class = " task m-auto" time = "00:00"

I have tried changing the function multiple times in multiple places and I still can manage to do it

```js
$(".task").each(function () {
    $(this).on("click", function () {
        var text = $(this).text().trim();
        var time = $(this).attr("time");
        console.log(time);

        if (text === "Enter task here") {
            var textInput = $("<input>").prop("maxlength", "114");
            $(this).replaceWith(textInput);
        }
        else {
            var textInput = $("<input>").prop("maxlength", "114").val(text);
            $(this).replaceWith(textInput);
        }
        textInput.trigger("focus");
    });

    $(this).on("blur", "input", function () {
        var text = $(this).val();

        var taskP = $("<p>").addClass("hour m-auto").text(text);
        console.log(taskP)

        if (text === null || text === "") {
            $("<p>").addClass("hour m-auto").prop("time", time).text("Enter task here");
            console.log("good")
        }
        else {
            $(this).replaceWith(taskP);
            console.log("bad")
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="timeList w-100 mt-3">
          <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
            <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:00</div>
            <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
              <p class="task m-auto" time="09:00">Enter task here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
            <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:10</div>
            <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
              <p class="task m-auto" time="09:10">Enter task here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
            <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:20</div>
            <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
              <p class="task m-auto" time="09:20">Enter task here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
            <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:30</div>
            <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
              <p class="task m-auto" time="09:30">Enter task here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
            <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:40</div>
            <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
              <p class="task m-auto" time="09:40">Enter task here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
            <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:50</div>
            <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
              <p class="task m-auto" time="09:50">Enter task here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
              <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ol>
```

Comment: Although it's possible to do what you're asking, why don't you just use `<input>`s to begin with and style them differently depending on their focus state?

Comment: I changed it all to textarea and still nothing

Comment: No, you misunderstand. Why are you trying to hide/show `input`s in the first place? How is this helping you achieve anything?

Comment: The whole goal is that there will be some text. the user can click in that text which will turn the text into an input for them to edit the text, and when they click away whatever they typed into the input would be the next text

Comment: Please check my answer. If this doesn't fully answer what you need then let me know and I will try to help. It's not too clear what you're after.

Comment: This solved it. I am still really new to using bootstrap and JQuery so I am still trying to figure out everything in your code. But it worked which has saved me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, hopefully this set you in the right direction.

The problem you had was that you were adding the "blur" event to elements that didn't exist yet.

Check out the use of deferred event handling below:

```js
$(".timeList").on("click", "p.task", function(e)
{
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  var time = $(this).attr("time");
  
  if (text === "Enter task here")
    text = "";
    
  let $textInput = $("<input>").addClass("task").attr("maxlength", "114").val(text);
    $(this).replaceWith($textInput);
    $textInput.trigger("focus");
});

$(".timeList").on("blur", "input.task", function(e)
{
  var text = $(this).val().trim();
  if(text === "") text = "Enter task here";
  var $taskP = $("<p>").addClass("task hour m-auto").text(text);

  $(this).replaceWith($taskP);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="timeList w-100 mt-3">
  <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:00</div>
    <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
      <p class="task m-auto" time="09:00">Enter task here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:10</div>
    <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
      <p class="task m-auto" time="09:10">Enter task here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:20</div>
    <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
      <p class="task m-auto" time="09:20">Enter task here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:30</div>
    <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
      <p class="task m-auto" time="09:30">Enter task here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:40</div>
    <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
      <p class="task m-auto" time="09:40">Enter task here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeSlot row shadow-sm mr-3 p-3 rounded">
    <div class="slotMinutes m-auto col-1">09:50</div>
    <div class="taskWrapper m-auto col-10">
      <p class="task m-auto" time="09:50">Enter task here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
      <button class="save"><i class="bi bi-check-square"></i></button>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".task", function() {
var text = $(this).text().trim();
var time = $(this).attr("time");
console.log(time);
if (text === "Enter task here") {
  var textInput = $("<input>").prop("maxlength", "114");
  $(this).replaceWith(textInput);
} else {
  var textInput = $("<input>").prop("maxlength", "114").val(text);
  $(this).replaceWith(textInput);
}
textInput.trigger("focus");});  $(document).on("blur", "input", function() {
var text = $(this).val();
var taskP = $("<p>").addClass("hour m-auto").text(text);
console.log(taskP)

if (text === null || text === "") {
  $("<p>").addClass("hour m-auto").prop("time", time).text("Enter task here");
  console.log("good")
} else {
  $(this).replaceWith(taskP);
  console.log("bad")
}});
```